# How to rollback a single conflict resolution during git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

In the middle of a long rebase I stumbled upon a following situation.
I got conflicts in several files and started resolving them one by one and marking resolutions with `git add`. After all was done I realized I made a mistake in one of resolutions. What to do now?

I know I can always issue `git rebase --abort` and start afresh, but is where a more selective way to just rollback a single commit resolution added to index?

Comment: after adding, did you commit?

Comment: no, I've just added the resolution to index.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't run `git rebase --continue` yet, you're in good shape.  You might want to save your incorrect-conflict-resolution version first since it may have a lot of correct stuff in it too:

```
cp path/to/wrong ~/tmp/save-wrong
```

for instance; then:

```
git checkout -m path/to/wrong
```

and you'll have the conflicts back again.

Answer (score 1):

If you do git log, this will give you a list of the commits.  Find the SHA1 and then do git checkout SHA1 to move the head to the point just before the mistake.

Comment: I guess that way I will lose conflict marks made by git.

Comment: have a read at this, might be useful: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html